# Format RFC3339 dates

Tags: objective-c, datetime, rfc3339

I am receiving the following date in string format from the API

```
2015-04-18 06:08:28.000000
```

I want the date to be in the format of `d/M/yyyy`

I tried the following

```
NSString *datevalue = (NSString*)value;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"d/M/yyyy"];
NSDate *date =  [formatter dateFromString:datevalue];
NSString *currentDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

This returns NIL, what could be the possible issue, or how do i format such dates in objective-c?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any control over the API's format for dates? Often RFC 3339/ISO 8601 dates include a `Z` at the end (to make it explicit that it is GMT/UTC/Zulu). And often there is a `T` between the date and year. You can use whatever format you want, but a common convention would be `2015-04-18T06:08:28.000000Z`.

Comment: The format string you use to read the character date should look vaguely like the string you're reading!! http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I have control over the API server, I'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS` format string for the date formatter converting the API date into a `NSDate` object, as discussed by the others. But, you also want to consider the `timeZone` and `locale` properties of this formatter.

- Usually RFC 3339 dates are exchanged in GMT. Confirm this with your API, but it's generally GMT/UTC/Zulu. If so, you will probably also want to explicitly set the timezone:

  ```
  formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
  ```

  But confirm what timezone the API expects.
- A more subtle issue is the handling users with non-Gregorian calendars

  ```
  formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
  ```

For more information, see Apple [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Clearly, these `dateFormat`, `timeZone`, and `locale` properties are simply for converting the API date string into a `NSDate` object. When then outputting the date for the end user, you would use a separate formatter, defaulting to the standard `timeZone` and `locale` properties and use whatever `dateFormat` string you want for the output. (Frankly, I wouldn't generally advise using `dateFormat` string for user output formatters, but rather just use the appropriate values for the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same formatter for read and writing the date string because they are the different. The format for your input date is incorrect.

```
// input string date: 2015-04-18 06:08:28.000000
// [formatter setDateFormat:@"d/M/yyyy"]; // incorrect
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];
```

Below is sample code

```
//
//  main.m
//  so29732496
//
//  Created on 4/19/15.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        NSString *dateStringFromAPI = @"2015-04-18 06:08:28.000000";
        NSString * const kAPIDateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS";

        // convert API date string
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:kAPIDateFormat];
        NSDate *apiDate =  [formatter dateFromString:dateStringFromAPI];


        // now if I was output the api date to another format
        // I have to change the formatter
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/M/yyyy"];
        NSString *currentDate = [formatter stringFromDate:apiDate];

        NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", currentDate);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used the wrong formatter for milliseconds.  It's capital S's.

Comment: Yes just like I wrote in my answer. If it worked out for you @IbrahimAzharArmar I would appreciate marking the answer as accepted since this way people who face the same problem can find the way to go easily. But I mean you have 8000 reputation points I think you know that by yourself, just a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to Black Frog's answer: As he stated you need different formatters for reading/writing.

However the right format should be :

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];
```

According to the apple documentation fractional seconds should be formatted with 'S'.

See here:
[NSDateFormat](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Also here is an example to accomplish your task:

```
    NSString *datevalue = @"2015-04-18 06:08:28.000000";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];
    NSDate *date =  [formatter dateFromString:datevalue];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *currentDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    NSLog(@"%@",currentDate);
```